# nested if-statement

Tags: ms-access

I dont know SQL nor nested-statements. Please provide me with the complete SQL to copy and paste into my Access query, based on my criteria and SQL below.
Thank you very much in advance, Nathaniel

**criteria**:

1. `if [POsoI].[PO_number]is like "*H", THEN [o].[SERVICE ID] must be equal to "HEAT TREAT"`
2. `IF [POsoI].[PO_number] is like "*C", THEN [o].[SERVICE ID] must 
   be equal to "COATING" or equal to "ZINC PLATING"`
3. `IF [POsoI].[PO_number] is like "*G", THEN [o].[SERVICE ID] must be 
   equal to "GRINDING"`
4. `IF  [POsoI].[.[PO_number] isnt like  "*H" or like  "*C" or like "*G", then [o].[SERVICE ID] must not be null and can not be equal to "HEAT TREAT" and can not be equal to "COATING" and can not be equal to"ZINC PLATING" and can not be equal to "GRINDING"`

   `SELECT DISTINCT o.SERVICE_ID
   FROM tbl_PO_service_order_input AS POsoI INNER JOIN SYSADM_OPERATION AS o ON (o.WORKORDER_LOT_ID = POsoI.WO_lot_ID) AND (POsoI.wo_Base_ID = o.WORKORDER_BASE_ID);`

Comment: [Teach Yourself SQL in 21 Days](http://www8.silversand.net/techdoc/teachsql/index.htm)

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: great comment :-)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but unfortunately, I don't have 21 days to learn.

Comment: It won't take 21 days, these criteria are basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT IIf(RIGHT(TBL_PO_SERVICE_ORDER_INPUT.PO_NUMBER,1)='H' And SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID='HEAT TREAT',SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID,IIf(RIGHT(TBL_PO_SERVICE_ORDER_INPUT.PO_NUMBER,1)='C' And SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID='CLOTHING' Or SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID='ZINC PLATING',SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID,IIf(RIGHT(TBL_PO_SERVICE_ORDER_INPUT.PO_NUMBER,1)='G' And SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID='GRINDING',SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID,IIf(RIGHT(TBL_PO_SERVICE_ORDER_INPUT.PO_NUMBER,1)<>'G' Or RIGHT(TBL_PO_SERVICE_ORDER_INPUT.PO_NUMBER,1)<>'H' Or RIGHT(TBL_PO_SERVICE_ORDER_INPUT.PO_NUMBER,1)<>'C' And SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID Is Not Null,SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID,
IIf(SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID<>'HEAT TREAT' And SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID<>'COATING' And SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID<>'ZINC PLATING' And SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID<>'GRINDING',SYSADM_OPERATION.SERVICE_ID)))))
FROM SYSADM_OPERATION INNER JOIN TBL_PO_SERVICE_ORDER_INPUT ON ([TBL_PO_SERVICE_ORDER_INPUT].WO_LOT_ID=[SYSADM_OPERATION].WORKORDER_LOT_ID) AND ([TBL_PO_SERVICE_ORDER_INPUT].WO_BASE_ID=[SYSADM_OPERATION].WORKORDER_BASE_ID);
```